# Quantile Estimation from Independent Estimates

Tags: estimation, quantiles

I need to estimate the 5th and 95th quantiles of a distribution. I have three independent quantile estimates for both the 5th and 95th quantiles. All estimates are obtained with the same technique on the same amount of independently generated data (N = 5000 in all three cases). Notice I only have the estimates, nothing else is left.

These estimates are equally valid, but is there a principled way to combine them together to get a better estimate? Intuitively, I am just calculating the mean of the estimates, but is there a way to justify this? Or is there something more meaningful to do?

Comment: What are you going to do with the estimates?

Comment: I am just reporting the .05-.95 interval as a result in a plot. No more calculation is done with the final estimate.